# Button creating hot key with key being non character

Tags: wpf, xaml

Hi I have wpf xaml button, I am trying to make a hot key for that button. I was able to find the code 
     
        
        
     
This code works fine but I am trying to add a third button and have the key value be a the plus sign ("+") like so:
     
When I try to do this I get an error Cannot convert "+". Any help  will be appreciated

All Code:

```
   <Window x:Class="WpfSample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="MyCommand1" Text="Text" />
        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="MyCommand2" Text="Another Text" />
        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="MyCommand3" Text="Another Text 2" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource MyCommand1}" 
                    Executed="FirstMethod" />
        <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource MyCommand2}" 
                    Executed="SecondMethod" />
        <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource MyCommand3}" 
                    Executed="ThirdMethod" />
    </Window.CommandBindings>

    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Z" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="{StaticResource MyCommand1}" />
        <KeyBinding Key="A" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="{StaticResource MyCommand2}" />
        <KeyBinding Key="+" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="{StaticResource MyCommand3}" />
    </Window.InputBindings>

    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="btn1" Command="{StaticResource MyCommand1}" Content="Click me"                 Visibility="Collapsed" />
        <Button x:Name="btn2" Command="{StaticResource MyCommand2}" Content="Click me" Visibility="Collapsed" />
        <Button x:Name="btn3" Command="{StaticResource MyCommand3}" Content="Click me" Visibility="Collapsed" />
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Comment: Show what code you have right now

Comment: how can I make KeyBinding Key="+" Modifiers="Ctrl" work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for the `OemPlus` or the `Add` key:

```
<KeyBinding Key="OemPlus" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="{StaticResource MyCommand3}" />
<KeyBinding Key="Add" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="{StaticResource MyCommand3}" />
```

Comment: Will this allow me hitting Ctrl and the plus sign (+) Ctrl++, because it cleared the error but I am not getting any of the code from function I attached